# Why is this bash variable empty when I just set it?

Tags: bash

```
$ sudo sh -c "FOO=bar echo Result:${FOO}"
Result:
```

Why is the value stored in FOO not displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because bash replaces `${FOO}` before calling `sudo`. So what `sh -c` actually sees is:

```
FOO=bar echo Result:
```

Besides, even if you tried

```
FOO=bar echo Result:${FOO}
```

It still won't work<sup>1</sup>. To get that right, you can do:

```
FOO=bar; echo Result:${FOO}
```

Now that that is fixed, let's get back to `sh -c`. To prevent bash from interpreting the string you are giving to `sh -c`, simply put it in `'` instead of `"`:

```
sudo sh -c 'FOO=bar; echo Result:${FOO}'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Refer to the comments for reason.</sub>

Comment: Yea, I'm really curious why you need the semicolon for it to work! That seems strange.

Comment: I know right? I had used `PATH=$PATH sudo ...` before because `sudo` resets `PATH` for security reasons and it was alright. I don't know why in this example it doesn't work.

Comment: `FOO=bar echo ...` sets the value of `FOO` in the environment in which `echo` will run; but `${FOO}` needs to be expanded before `echo` actually runs in that environment.

Comment: @chepner, obvious once explained! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, because the variable `FOO` is set for the following command, `echo`, but the `${FOO}` is replaced by the enclosing shell.

If you want it to work, you must set the variable `FOO` for the enclosing shell and wrap the `echo ...` in single quotes

```
sudo FOO=bar sh -c 'echo Result:${FOO}'
```